# Unbricking a phone without being able to access recovery

Tags: adb, root-access, unbricking, fastboot

I have rooted my Zenfone 2 ZE551ML using a method which permanently replaces recovery (I didn't realize it back then). Can I unbrick it using only fastboot? I can't use adb, as I can't open recovery. I basically need a fastboot `adb sideload` alternative for flashing the entire firmware/ROM. I tried to flash every single part (except for the system.img, which I couldn't flash) of the firmware using fastboot separately, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you search for an appropriate recovery, and flash it with fastboot first?

Comment: You mean, to flash a recovery using fastboot? Didn't work.

Comment: I see. I think that it'll be better to summon @Firelord. He's the fastboot expert, after all.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know the experts here, **yet**.

Comment: Oh @firelord ! We have some presents! In the form of fastboot based problems!

Comment: @DanB Firelord was summoned already, yet he still hasn't come to see his presents.

Comment: @Samuel Shifterovich I know, but I had to say it. There was too much temptation

Comment: Quick reminder that you can't @mention someone who didn't participate in the question yet (it will have no effect).

Comment: @Xan Right. So you can't summon someone, you can only wait if/when they will see the question?

Comment: Yes, StackExchange is engineered on purpose that there's no way to contact a user.

Comment: Bad purpose. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can flash a new recovery image with fastboot.
The command is:

`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`

where 'recovery.img' is the name of the image.

If you enter fasboot on the command line with no options or parameters you will see the usage, which is: 

`fastboot flash [partition] [filename]`

Comment: Flashing a new recovery didn't help. Neither stock nor twrp worked.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Did you receive an error? Was there any output at all?

Comment: Stock: Couldn't get over that button combination protection thing
TWRP: When I opened recovery, it rebooted.